# Apples keyboard appears then scroll code sample does not work correctly

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, keyboard, scroll

I have a UITableView with a navigation bar on top. I have several text fields in the cells and if i click in the cell at the bottom the keyboard hides the text field. So I googled and found this link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7

I used exactly that code and run my app again. Now it scrolls up (about the height of the keyboard) instead of scrolling down. Also it scrolls in every cell, even the cells at the top which will not get hided by the keyboard. Does anyone have a solution for this? I tried to log out some coordinates inside the keyWasShown: method but it's very complex for me to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I used trial and error and finally found out, that I have to add two superview properties behind activeField:

```
activeField.superview.superview.frame.origin
```

Do this behind every activeField in the method keyboardWasShown: and it will work. Ah and I added 70 pixels, because the view didn't scroll exactly where I wanted it to, maybe it is because of the navigation bar I use, I don't know:

```
activeField.superview.superview.frame.origin.y - kbSize.height + 70
```